# Get Device Info. with EmailIntent

Tags: android

how to gather user data like,
OS version, Phone Model etc using the EXTRA_TEXT in emailIntent?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYMTa.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate class like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;

public class Utils {

    public static String buildDeviceUserInformation(Context context) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append(String.format("Device: %s\n", getDeviceName()));
        builder.append(String.format("OS: %s\n", Build.VERSION.RELEASE));
        builder.append(String.format("App Version: %1$s/%2$s\n", getAppVersion(context), getAppVersionCode(context)));

        String carrierName = getCarrier(context);

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(carrierName))
            builder.append(String.format("Carrier: %1$s\n", carrierName));

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static String getCarrier(Context context) {
        try {
            TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            return manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static String getDeviceName() {
        String device = Build.MANUFACTURER;

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(Build.MODEL)) {
            device = TextUtils.isEmpty(device) ? Build.MODEL : device + " " + Build.MODEL;
    }

        return device;
    }

    public static String getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            return context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public static Integer getAppVersionCode(Context context) {
        try {
            return context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your intent just use it like this:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Utils.buildDeviceUserInformation(AboutMeActivity.this));
```

Output would look like this:

```
Device: LGE Nexus 5
OS: 6.0.1
App Version: 10.70/1070
```

Comment: its throw Error like unknown entity Context.. & unknown Modifier static.

Comment: @user6330086 just updated the answer. Just copy all the code above, it should work now

Comment: Thnks, the Utils doesnt throw error now... Just the 2nd Code Utils.buildDeviceUserInformation(this)); throws error android.content.context cannot be applied here

Comment: Updated. If you call `buildDeviceUserInformation` method inside an anonymous class in your activity, then instead of passing `this`, you need to pass `YourActivityName.this`

Comment: Thanks a Lot Kirill! Works Awesome :)

Comment: can u plzz help on dis issue?
stackoverflow.com/questions/39054729/android-download-manager-shows-complete-but-later-shows-unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

To get the OS Version, simply use `Build.VERSION.RELEASE`

As for the Device Model, you can use

```
public static String getDeviceModel() {
    return Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL;
}
```

Then when you want to include this in the text of your emailIntent, simply use :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
//Device model
builder.append(getDeviceModel())
            .append("\n");
//OS
builder.append(Build.VERSION.RELEASE);

intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, builder.toString());
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Contact us");
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```